# iOS pie chart properties

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I´m using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for iOS and have a pie chart. I would like to remove the inner circle and change the width for each pie inside the pie chart. I have not been able to find how to decrease the width for the pie chart and remove the inner circle.

The image is what I want to do.

[image: Chart]

I have tried on my `PieChartView` to change the `draw` properties but have not succeeded. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How to give border to each slice in this library ?

Answer (score 15):

`PieChartView` has the following properties:

1. `holeRadiusPercent`
2. `transparentCircleRadiusPercent`

Set them both to `0.0` and you should achieve what you want.

You can also hide the hole explicitly by setting `chartView.drawHoleEnabled = false`

If you need more properties, just open the [source code](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Charts/PieChartView.swift). It is heavily commented.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @sulthan's response with some example code.

The CGSize of the chart view's frame can be modified to affect the chart width itself.

However, a CGSize which exceeds the CGSize of the chart's parent view may result in unpredictable layouts.

```
let chart = PieChartView( frame: self.view.frame)
// setup data...etc.

// style
chart.holeRadiusPercent = 0
chart.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear

// increase width
// width in excess of the parentView.size.width will cause layout issues
chart.frame.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: chart.frame.size.height)
```

Shameless plug: Learn more about iOS Pie charts at [ioscharts.io/piechart](http://ioscharts.io/piechart)

[image]

Comment: The website was very helpful!